# Hanging posters from wall

Tags: hanging

I have some posters of movies and other stuff which I like to have around. I recently shifted cities and rented a place for myself to stay. I can't stick the posters to the walls with cellotape as it might peel off the paint if removed. Also, the landlord won't allow it. Is there anything I can do to hang the posters with threads or ropes or certain frames which can be used?

I live in India, so please suggest methods that use materials available in India.

I was thinking of using 2 binder clips to hold the poster and tie the clips with thread which will pass over a nail in the wall.

Any other inexpensive suggestions?

Comment: Well wouldn't this leave a hole in the wall? This is far worse than using cello tapes. Just be careful when you are moving posters and use tape.

Comment: Are these walls drywalls? Masonry? Wooden?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, binder clips are a great solution. You can put a tiny tack or pin to hang each clip on directly, without using string. If this is "real" paper artwork (like a drawing, print or silkscreen), put a small piece of archival paper, or any good-quality paper, between the clip and the artwork to protect the art from rust or the clip if the air is damp. The front wire of the binder clip can be compressed and it will pop off easily, making a nice clean look. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it and it works, but the problem is the posters were rolled during delivery. I am putting binder clips only on top side. Thus the posters curls upwards. Also, it keeps flying when fan is turned on. Any idea how to keep it straight?

Comment: Have you tried putting binder clips on the bottom corners too to stop it from curling back up?

Comment: Yes, Doresroom's suggestion is a good one. You can also tack down all four clips so the fan doesn't blow it around. Eventually the poster will relax on its own.

Comment: Another option is to sandwich the top and bottom of the poster between slats of wood. This gives you a nice straight top and bottom, plus a bit of weight to keep the poster hanging straight. Along those lines, you can also get a piece of archival (aka acid-free) foam core or matt board cut to the size of the poster and use that as a backing to keep it straight/stiff.

Comment: My suggestion is, to add something to Doresoom and DA01 comments, that You can place 2 pins in some distance like, 2 meters, then place some kind of a string (elastic thread that fishermen use) between them. If You place them firmly, You will be able to put like 2-3 posters on the string. Same thing for bottom corners (string to support bottoms).